# Cannot Run Some Commands on Android

Tags: android, busybox

I have rooted my mobile. I am able to get root login even then I am not able to delete some system files and also some general linux commands like sort doesn't run

Comment: Cool, are you here to gloat or do you want to ask a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 questions 
First you are not able to delete the files even in root login

This generally happens when a file has attributes i, a, u are set.
You Can check this by command

lsattr file.name

to change it use

chattr -iau file.name

now you will be able to delete the file.

Second some command doesn't run

In order to work most of linux commands in android you need busybox. It is a package which allow users to execute most of the linux command. you can download this busybox file and put it inside /system/bin/

then to use it

$ busybox sort

Comment: use busybox then for it

$busybox lsattr file.name

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing the system over USB-Debugging or on the Android itself? Furthermore if you do it over the Android, which software do you use? And please provide the commands you wanted to execute.